# Why non-explicit splat param plus default param is wrong syntax for method definition in Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby

I'd like to ask why having a splat param1 and a param2 with default value assignment in Ruby-1.9.3-p0 as below:

`def my_method(*param1, param2 = "default"); end`

returns

`SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'`

My workaround is explicitly wrap param1 in brackets like this:

`def my_method((*param1), param2 = "default"); end`

Many thanks

Comment: Marc is right, your work around doesn't actually work. Try `o.my_method(1, 2, 3)` and see what happens.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ruby can't parse a parameter with a default after a splat.  If you have default assignment in a parameter after a splat, how would Ruby know what to assign the variable to?

```
def my_method(*a, b = "foo"); end
```

Let's say I then call my_method:

```
my_method(1, 2, 3)
```

Ruby has no way of knowing whether b is missing, in which case you want b to be foo and a is [1,2,3], or if b is present in which case you want it to be 3.